# Creating a loop to complete statistical models on multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I want to run these five Confirmatory Factor Analysis models in eleven separate dataframes:

```
library(lavaan)

cfa(CFA_Models$OneFactor, data=PHQ_Stroke_Author1, estimator = "WLS")
cfa(CFA_Models$TwoFactor, data=PHQ_Stroke_Author1, estimator = "WLS")
cfa(CFA_Models$AlternativeTwoFactor, data=PHQ_Stroke_Author1, estimator = "WLS")
cfa(CFA_Models$BiFactor, data=PHQ_Stroke_Author1, estimator = "WLS")
cfa(CFA_Models$BiFactorAlternativeFactor, data=PHQ_Stroke_Author1, estimator = "WLS")
```

where "data=PHQ_Stroke_Author1" refers to the first dataframe of 11.

The dataframes have predictable names i.e. PHQ_Stroke_[author name]

I would like to create a FOR loop, so that any changes to the original model can quickly be conducted for all 11 dataframes. However, I am new to R and not sure how to execute this.

So far I have compiled a list of dataframes for the FOR loop to run through:

`Dataframes<-list(df1, df2, df3...)`

I would then like the FOR loop to input each dataframe in the CFA code "data=..." i.e.
cfa(CFA_Models$OneFactor, **data=PHQ_Stroke_Author1**, estimator = "WLS").

Please could you offer guidance on how to build this into a for loop and create it as a function?

I don't know exactly how the code would look, but something like this?

```
for(i in Dataframes){
CFA_Fit_[[i]]<-cfa(CFA_Models$OneFactor, data=[[i]], estimator = "WLS")
CFA_Fit_[[i]]<-cfa(CFA_Models$TwoFactor, data=[[i]], estimator = "WLS")
CFA_Fit_[[i]]<-cfa(CFA_Models$AlternativeTwoFactor, data=[[i]], estimator = "WLS")
CFA_Fit_[[i]]<-cfa(CFA_Models$BiFactor, data=[[i]], estimator = "WLS")
CFA_Fit_[[i]]<-cfa(CFA_Models$BiFactorAlternativeFactor, data=[[i]], estimator = "WLS"
}
```

This is obviously completely wrong, but I'm not sure what the correct solution is.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with a column `value` containing the data for each dataset (3 rows in total, one for each element in `Dataframes`).
Then, mutate / map pattern can be done to apply a function to each element of the column. Alternatively, one can also use `lapply` if meta data is not required to be stored in other columns.

```r
library(tidyverse)
Dataframes <- list(iris, iris, iris)

Dataframes %>%
  enframe() %>%
  mutate(model = value %>% map(~ lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .x)))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>    name value          model 
#>   <int> <list>         <list>
#> 1     1 <df [150 × 5]> <lm>  
#> 2     2 <df [150 × 5]> <lm>  
#> 3     3 <df [150 × 5]> <lm>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>